# Why my javascript snippets is extremely slow in vscode?

Tags: node.js, visual-studio-code, autocomplete, intellisense

I don't know why but my javascript snippet is extremely slow compared to other language, such as php, particularly when I code with node js. Plain javascript for front end is doing fine

[image: this is when I code with php]

The snippet is fast and fluid, no problem at all

[image: this is when I code with node js]

The snippet is extremely slow. Personally, snippets are a great help for me for faster workload, especially if the method/variable name is long

Comment: Did you solve it in the end?